# CoreML : `Failed to get the home directory when checking model path` error

Tags: xcode, swiftui, coreml, text-recognition, apple-vision

I am using this code for extracting text from image, First time the code runs perfectly after that its start giving this error message `[coreml] Failed to get the home directory when checking model path`. Here is the code that I am using to extract text form image. This is the same code that I have copied from that I have copied from [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/structuring_recognized_text_on_a_document)

```
func requestORC(image: UIImage) {
        
        //        guard let cgImage = UIImage(named: "test")?.cgImage else { return }
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return }
        
        //        / Create a new image-request handler.
        let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage)
        
        // Create a new request to recognize text.
        let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: recognizeTextHandler)
        
        do {
            // Perform the text-recognition request.
            try requestHandler.perform([request])
        } catch {
            print("Unable to perform the requests: \(error).")
        }
        
    }
    
    func recognizeTextHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        guard let observations =
                request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {
            return
        }
        let recognizedStrings = observations.compactMap { observation in
            // Return the string of the top VNRecognizedText instance.
            return observation.topCandidates(1).first?.string
        }
        // Process the recognized strings.
//        print(recognizedStrings)
        
        self.recognizedStrings = recognizedStrings
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Getting rid of the error in simulator...

It may sound very strange but the `Failed to get the home directory when checking model path` error occurs in Xcode simulator only when you running a text recognition app with the default `.accurate` case of a request's recognition level. Change the value to `.fast` and the error will disappear.

It should also be said that when running the code on an actual device, the above error does not appear at all.

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Vision
import CoreML

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var recognizedStrings = [String]()
    @State var interpolatedString = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()

            Text(interpolatedString)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.horizontal, 100)
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.opticalCharacterRecognition(.init(named: "make.png")!)
            
            if recognizedStrings.count > 0 {
                for i in 0 ..< recognizedStrings.count {
                    interpolatedString += recognizedStrings[i] + " "
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension ContentView {

    func opticalCharacterRecognition(_ image: UIImage) {
        guard let pngData = image.pngData() else { return }
        let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(data: pngData)
        
        let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: textHandler)
        
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        print("No more errors...")
        request.recognitionLevel = .fast      // Here it is
#endif
        
        do {
            try requestHandler.perform([request])
        } catch {
            print("Unable to perform the requests: \(error).")
        }
    }
    
    func textHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation]
        else { return }
        let recognizedStrings = observations.compactMap { observation in
            return observation.topCandidates(1).first?.string
        }
        self.recognizedStrings = recognizedStrings
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apparently `VNRequestTextRecognitionLevel.accurate` uses a neural engine, which is not supported on the simulator.